# auto process with DLQ configuration in spring xd

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd

1)I want to configure DLQ for my stream

```
 stream create --name httptest7 --definition "http |  http-client --url='''http://localhost:8080/mock-sentmessage/customers/send-email''' --httpMethod=GET | log" 
stream deploy httptest7 --properties module.*.consumer.autoBindDLQ=true
```

2)I have made

```
autoBindDLQ=true
```

I had one doubt if suppose spring xd fails to process my messages and post it to dlq .Will they me automatically moved to My original queue to retry or should i write  a processor  to move my DLQ messages to my original queue

3)Now i bring down my webservice `http://localhost:8080/mock-sentmessage/customers/send-email` i can see message  filling in my dlq.

4)When i bring up my service up . But as per my understanding  I thought from DLQ the message will be retried again  when my service is up.

But From DLQ its not retried again .Any configuration I need to set for ?

As per documentation:

There is no automated mechanism provided to move dead lettered messages back to the bus queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your question is, or even if you have one; you seem to have answered your own question by quoting the documentation:

> There is no automated mechanism provided to move dead lettered messages back to the bus queue.

So, no; there is no "setting" you can change.

There are a couple of things you can do - write your own code to move the messages back to the main queue from the DLQ; it would just take a few lines of Java using Spring AMQP, or in any language of your choice.

You can also use the [technique described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357820/rabbitmq-with-spring-amqp-messages-stuck-in-case-of-amqpexception/28358510#28358510) whereby you set a message TTL on the DLQ, and configure it to route back to the main queue when the TTL expires.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, You can use shovel plugin in Rabbitmq to do the movement from DLQ back to the bus queue.