# Requeueing dead letter messages

Tags: spring-amqp

Is there any functionality built in to spring-amqp that would make it easy to requeue dead letter messages? I can write code to do it but it seems like such a common use case that would fit well into the framework.

Comment: Can you be more detail than in your below comment ? Is there exists a way  to set a limit for requeuing some message ? I mean something like that: Give three chances for requeuing for each message. After three messages reject it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is outside of Spring AMQP, but you can configure a TTL on the dead letter queue and configure **that** queue to dead-letter back to the original queue when expired.

You can check the `x-death` header if you want to give up completely after some number of retry cycles.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640358/spring-amqp-with-rabbitmq-message-is-not-circled-back-to-live-queue-after-falli/27641433#27641433) and its question for more information.

Comment: Gary this works great. We hit something today as a result of implementing this that I thought I would share for your future reference. We had a case in our dev environment where a MessageListener was erroring out over and over. We eventually started seeing errors in RabbitMQ of frame_too_large. After researching we found in the RabbitMQ documentation that an array gets added to the x-death header you mentioned each time a message is dead lettered. Since our solution sets up an endless cycle the message got too large and it eventually blew up. Future readers might want to consider a max retry.

Comment: @JoshChappelle with newer versions of the broker, the `x-death` header contains only one entry per queue visited and updates a count each time, instead of extending the header on each round.

Comment: Yep we have upgraded our broker and no longer have that problem. Thanks for mentioning that.